# I don't know why my IOCP's numberOfConcurrentThreads argument doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, iocp

I have read a material below and tested some code.
[Does IOCP creates its own threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648802/does-iocp-creates-its-own-threads)

My codes are as below:

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

namespace IOCP_test {
    struct myOverlapped {
        OVERLAPPED overLapped;
        int number;
    };

    DWORD WINAPI myCallBack(LPVOID completionPort) {
        DWORD NumberOfByteTransfered = 0;
        VOID* CompletionKey = NULL;
        OVERLAPPED* overlappedPointer = NULL;


        while (true) {
            auto success = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
                (HANDLE)completionPort,
                &NumberOfByteTransfered,
                (LPDWORD)&CompletionKey,
                &overlappedPointer,
                INFINITE);


            if (success) {
                myOverlapped* mO = (myOverlapped*)overlappedPointer;
                while (true) {
                    cout << mO->number << endl;
                }
                //Sleep(10);
                //PostQueuedCompletionStatus(completionPort, 0, 0, overlappedPointer);
            }
        }
    }


    void IOCP_test() { 
        // TODO: sleep을 안걸었는데.. 왜 5개 스레드가 모두 작동할까?
        int workerThreadCount = 5; 
        HANDLE hIOCP = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1);
        vector<HANDLE> workerThreadVector;

        DWORD NumberOfByteTransfered = 0;
        VOID* CompletionKey = NULL;
        OVERLAPPED* overlappedPointer = NULL;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < workerThreadCount; i++)
        {
            HANDLE WorkerThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myCallBack, hIOCP, 0, NULL);
            workerThreadVector.push_back(WorkerThread);
        }

        myOverlapped a1;
        a1.number = 1;

        myOverlapped a2;
        a2.number = 2;

        myOverlapped a3;
        a3.number = 3;

        myOverlapped a4;
        a4.number = 4;

        myOverlapped a5;
        a5.number = 5;

        if (hIOCP) {
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a1);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a2);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a3);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a4);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a5);
        }

        char key;
        while (true) {
            key = _getch();

            if (key == 'e') {
                break;
            }

            if (key == 'n') {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < workerThreadVector.size(); i++)
        {
            CloseHandle(workerThreadVector[i]);
        }

        if (hIOCP) {
            CloseHandle(hIOCP);
        }
    }
    //IOCP_test::IOCP_test();

}

int main()
{
    IOCP_test::IOCP_test();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  
    return 0;
}
```

I thought, if numberOfConcurrentThreads works,  only a thread that cout '1' should be running, not all five threads.

However, result is as below.
[image]

All overlapped works were being processed by worker threads..

Why all overlapped works were processed by 5 worker threads?
I think it should be 1 worker thread that works because numberOfConcurrentThreads is 1.

I hope your wise answers.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: and ? your code nothing show at all.

Comment: Don't you see my code above?

Comment: some code, and ? how it related to your question about numberOfConcurrentThreads ?

Comment: Sorry for late. I have been working all day..
You can see what is 'numberOfConcurrentThreads' on below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-createiocompletionport

It is the fourth argument of function 'CreateIoCompletionPort' and it controls the number of running worker threads on IOCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
It is because I called 'cout' in my worker thread's function.
I think 'cout' invokes IO interrupt for my worker thread, and it makes IOCP signal another worker thread.

My test code is as below.
You can run this code, and press any key except 'e'.('e' is for exit.)
You can see which worker thread works in IOCP.

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>

int iocp_test = -1;


namespace IOCP_test {
    struct myOverlapped {
        OVERLAPPED overLapped;
        int number;
    };

    DWORD WINAPI myCallBack(LPVOID completionPort) {
        DWORD NumberOfByteTransfered = 0;
        VOID* CompletionKey = NULL;
        OVERLAPPED* overlappedPointer = NULL;


        while (true) {
            auto success = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
                (HANDLE)completionPort,
                &NumberOfByteTransfered,
                (LPDWORD)&CompletionKey,
                &overlappedPointer,
                INFINITE);


            if (success) {
                myOverlapped* mO = (myOverlapped*)overlappedPointer;
                while (true) {
                    iocp_test = mO->number;
                }
                //Sleep(10);
                //PostQueuedCompletionStatus(completionPort, 0, 0, overlappedPointer);
            }
        }
    }


    void IOCP_test() { 
        // sleep을 안걸었는데.. 왜 5개 스레드가 모두 작동할까? 
        // cout 같은 IO 인터럽트가 워커 스레드에서 호출되면 IOCP에서 그 스레드는 작업 중이 아닌 스레드로 판단하는 것 같다.
        int workerThreadCount = 5; 
        HANDLE hIOCP = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 2); 
        vector<HANDLE> workerThreadVector;

        DWORD NumberOfByteTransfered = 0;
        VOID* CompletionKey = NULL;
        OVERLAPPED* overlappedPointer = NULL;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < workerThreadCount; i++)
        {
            HANDLE WorkerThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myCallBack, hIOCP, 0, NULL);
            workerThreadVector.push_back(WorkerThread);
        }

        myOverlapped a1;
        a1.number = 1;

        myOverlapped a2;
        a2.number = 2;

        myOverlapped a3;
        a3.number = 3;

        myOverlapped a4;
        a4.number = 4;

        myOverlapped a5;
        a5.number = 5;

        if (hIOCP) {
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a1);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a2);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a3);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a4);
            PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)&a5);
        }

        char key;
        while (true) {
            key = _getch();
            cout << iocp_test;
            if (key == 'e') {
                break;
            }

            if (key == 'n') {
                cout << endl;
            }

        }

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < workerThreadVector.size(); i++)
        {
            CloseHandle(workerThreadVector[i]);
        }

        if (hIOCP) {
            CloseHandle(hIOCP);
        }
    }
    //IOCP_test::IOCP_test();

}


int main()
{

    IOCP_test::IOCP_test();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();  
    return 0;
}
```